# How to mark all checkboxes in AngularJs in custom table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this table in angular that I send her data and it shows it, deepens on the data. I also add cheackbox input that i want when i click on it he mark all the checkboxes, but he doesn't work very well.

Here is the directive of angular:

```
app.directive("tables", function(){
return {
template: '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">'+
    '<thead>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<th>#</th>'+
        '<th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll(values)" /></th>'+
        '<th ng-repeat="(key,label) in labels">'+
            '<a href="" ng-click="orderByField=key; reverseSort = !reverseSort">'+
            '{{ label }} '+
                '<span ng-show="orderByField == key" class="sortIcon">'+
                    '<span ng-show="reverseSort">'+
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>'+
                    '</span>'+
                    '<span ng-show="!reverseSort">'+
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>'+
                    '</span>'+
                '</span>'+
            '</a>'+
        '</th>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</thead>'+
'<tbody>'+
  '<tr ng-repeat="(what,items) in values | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | filter :searchInput  " >'+
    '<td>{{ $index +1 }}</td>'+
    '<td> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.select" value="{{ items[fieldId] }}"></td>'+
    '<td ng-repeat="(key,item) in items" ng-if="item != items[fieldId] ">{{item}}</td>'+
  '</tr>'+
'</tbody>'+
'</table>',
 link: function($scope) {

      $scope.checkAll = function(arraySelect) {
        angular.forEach(arraySelect, function(user) {
          user.select = $scope.selectAll;
        });
     };

    }
  }
});
```

Here is the full example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/23b9f4r1/9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.
i define `values` as `scope` in directive. and also remove value from checkbox.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23b9f4r1/10/)

```js
app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http){

 $scope.customers = [];
 $scope.orderByField = "first_name";
 $scope.reverseSort = false;
 $scope.pageTitle = "CUSTOMERS_TXT";
 $scope.fieldId = "id";
 
 $scope.values = [
                      {first_name: "Oded", last_name: "Taizi", id: 1,select:false},
                      {first_name: "Ploni", last_name: "Almoni", id: 2,select:false}
                      ];
 
 $scope.labels =  ["first_name","last_name"];
 
});

app.directive("tables", function(){
return {
  scope:{
   values:'=values'
 },
   template: '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">'+
  '<thead>'+
  '<tr>'+
   '<th>#</th>'+
        '<th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll(selectAll)" /></th>'+
   '<th ng-repeat="(key,label) in labels">'+
    '<a href="" ng-click="orderByField=key; reverseSort = !reverseSort">'+
    '{{ label }} '+
     '<span ng-show="orderByField == key" class="sortIcon">'+
            '<span ng-show="reverseSort">'+
             '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>'+
            '</span>'+
            '<span ng-show="!reverseSort">'+
             '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>'+
            '</span>'+
           '</span>'+
          '</a>'+
   '</th>'+
  '</tr>'+
 '</thead>'+
 '<tbody>'+
   '<tr ng-repeat="(what,items) in values | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | filter :searchInput  " >'+
    '<td>{{ $index +1 }}{{items}}</td>'+
    '<td> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="items.select" ></td>'+
     '<td ng-repeat="(key,item) in items" ng-if="item != items[fieldId] ">{{item}}</td>'+
   '</tr>'+
 '</tbody>'+
 '</table>',
   link: function($scope) {

          $scope.checkAll = function(selectAll) {
            angular.forEach($scope.values, function(user) {
             user.select = selectAll;
            });
         };

        }
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <tables values="values"></tables>
  </div>
</div>
```